# ALL() and REMOVEFILTER() Don't Work Correctly on My Report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem that showing Lifetime amount by using *ALL() or REMOVEFILTERS()* functions on my report.

I have created a new date table as slicer that implies **Yesterday, Last 7 Days, Same Day Last Month, All, Custom** etc., and it works perfect. But when I selected any slicer rather than **"All"**, Lifetime Revenue does not show correct amount.

Since the new slicer table consists duplicate dates, the cross-filter direction on relationship is not single as below.

[Link to the file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5166e4fe6803a1ceafff5554f32f1a2620240330183511/5ca780)

The dax query, I've used is to get Life Time Revenue:

```
Revenue_Lifetime = 
 CALCULATE(
    SUM(Revenue[Revenue]),
    ALL('Date Periods'[Date],'Date Periods'[Type])
 )
```

Here is a sample report that shows the problem:

[SampleReport](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5166e4fe6803a1ceafff5554f32f1a2620240330183511/5ca780)

Thank you,

Kisa